# Joomla 3.x Override button functions in custom component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to override the buttons in my joomla component.

I've managed fine with the save function by adding code into the controller.

```
            public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null)
                {
                    $uri = JUri::getInstance(); 


                    $requestData = JRequest::getVar('jform', array(), 'post', 'array');
                    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
                    $userId = $user->get( 'id' );

                    $idToUse = $requestData['id'];
```

I want to do the same thing with save and close and save and new but I can't figure out how to do it.  I thought that I needed to go to the view.html and look at the custom functions:

```
            JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_SHOPPER_TITLE_SELECTOR'), 'selector.png');

            // If not checked out, can save the item.
            if (!$checkedOut && ($canDo->get('core.edit') || ($canDo->get('core.create'))))
            {
                JToolBarHelper::apply('selector.apply', 'JTOOLBAR_APPLY');
                JToolBarHelper::save('selector.save', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');
            }

            if (!$checkedOut && ($canDo->get('core.create')))
            {
                JToolBarHelper::custom('selector.save2new', 'save-new.png', 'save-new_f2.png', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE_AND_NEW', false);
            }
```

So I thought I just needed to add a function save2new() but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong would be great.

Comment: Usually building a function in the controller will do your needs. Do you get an error message? What does the system do in case of clicking the save2new button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `registerTask`.

If you want to call save method for `save2new` task than you need to call `registerTask` inside constructor `__constructor`

```
$this->registerTask('save2new', 'save');
```

https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JController::registerTask